# display divs side by side up to n divs, every div with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, html, css

div (or) li display divs side by side up to 3 divs every div with dynamic height and adjust divs dynamically.
[adjust divs dynamically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVcMr.png)

Comment: https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
*{margin: 0px auto;}
ul{ width: 80%;  position: relative; }
ul li{list-style: none; width: 30%; height: auto; border: 1px solid blue; position:absolute; }
</style>


<ul id = "ulh" class="newblog-container" >
<li style="left:0%;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x120&text=image1">
</li>
<li style="left:33.33%;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300&text=image2">
</li>
<li style="left:66.66%;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x220&text=image3">
</li>
<li style="left:0%;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x320&text=image4">
</li>
<li style="left:33.33%;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x220&text=image5">
</li>
<li style="left:66.66%;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x520&text=image6">
</li>
<li style="left:0%;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x320&text=image7">
</li>
<li style="left:33.33%;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x350&text=image8">
</li>
<li style="left:66.66%;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x520&text=image9">
</li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">    
jQuery(window).load(function() { 
for (var i = 0; i < jQuery( ".newblog-container li" ).length; i++) 
{
   if(i > 2 & i < 6){ jQuery( ".newblog-container li" ).eq(i).css({'top' : jQuery( ".newblog-container li" ).eq(i-3).outerHeight() +'px'}); }
   if(i >= 6){ var p = jQuery( ".newblog-container li" ).eq(i-3); var position = p.position();
    jQuery( ".newblog-container li" ).eq(i).css({'top' : position.top + jQuery( ".newblog-container li" ).eq(i-3).outerHeight() +'px'}); }
};
var p2 = jQuery( ".newblog-container li" ).last(); var position2 = p2.position(); var lip = position2.top;  
var llih3 = jQuery( ".newblog-container li" ).eq(-3).height();
var llih2 = jQuery( ".newblog-container li" ).eq(-2).height();
var llih1 = jQuery( ".newblog-container li" ).eq(-1).height();
var numbers_array = [llih3, llih2, llih1];
var biggest = Math.max.apply( null, numbers_array );
var z = lip + biggest + 'px';
 jQuery('.newblog-container').css({'height' : lip + biggest + 'px'});

});
</script>
```

Comment: See the Result in full page

Answer (score 0):

- You can use js to set 'position' as 'absolute'
- You can change 'cols' in js to change the number of columns

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #main {
      position:relative;
    }
    .box {
      width: 300px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      float:left;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .box p{
      width: 300px;
      margin: 10px  auto;
      border-radius:5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="box">
      <p>1 convallis timestamp</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p>2 convallis timestamp 2 Donec a fermentum nisi. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p>3 Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula
   faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc
   convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula
   faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc
   convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.Nullam eget lectus augue. Donec eu sem sit amet ligula
   faucibus suscipit. Suspendisse rutrum turpis quis nunc
   convallis quis aliquam mauris suscipit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p> 4 Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut
 sagittis vitae, egestas at augue. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p> 5 Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p> 6 Donec a fermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p> 7 Donec a ermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p> 8 Donec a ermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p> 9 Donec a ermentum nisi. Integer dolor est, commodo ut sagittis vitae, egestas at augue.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

<script>
window.onload=function(){
  waterfall("main","box");
};
function waterfall(parent,box){
  var oParent=document.getElementById(parent);
  var oBoxs=getByClass(oParent,box); // 'box' List
  //Calculate the number of columns displayed across the page (page width, box width)
  var oBoxW=312; // width of box
  var cols=3; // number of columns
  // set the width of 'main'
  oParent.style.cssText="width:"+oBoxW*cols+"px;margin:0 auto";
  var hArr=[];
  for(var i=0;i<oBoxs.length;i++){
    if(i<cols){
      hArr.push(oBoxs[i].offsetHeight);
    } else {
      oBoxs[i].style.position="absolute";
      oBoxs[i].style.top=hArr[i%cols] + 10*Math.floor(i/cols) +"px";
      oBoxs[i].style.left=oBoxW*(i%cols)+"px";
      hArr[i%cols]=hArr[i%cols] + oBoxs[i].offsetHeight;
    }
  }
}
//Get the element based on it's class
function getByClass(parent,clsName){
  var boxArr=new Array();
  var oElements=parent.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for(var i=0;i<oElements.length;i++){
    if(oElements[i].className==clsName){
      boxArr.push(oElements[i]);
    }
  }
  return boxArr;
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVcMr.png
need to display vertically i was updated the image